# Change from static image to Google Map onhover or mouse in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, google-maps, onmouseover

I would like to have a static image that is replaced by Google Maps on hover or mouse over. I am trying to use the plugin Hover Image but I don't think you can use the Google Map code in there because it isn't working. Is there another way? Thank you so much in advance!

This is what I have tried using the Hover Image Plugin and placing the shortcode [himage]  [/himage] as requried around the below code but it only shows the first image and does not pick up the Google Map. How do I get it to pick up the Google Map?

```
[himage]
<img class="" title="" src="http://tafe404.cccit.info/loosh2/wp-content/themes/newtheme/images/loosh_map.png" alt="Map showing location of LOOSH" width="463" height="463" align="center" />


[google-map-v3 width="463" height="463" zoom="16" maptype="roadmap" mapalign="center" directionhint="false" language="default" poweredby="false" maptypecontrol="true" pancontrol="true" zoomcontrol="true" scalecontrol="true" streetviewcontrol="true" scrollwheelcontrol="true" draggable="true" tiltfourtyfive="false" addmarkermashupbubble="false" addmarkermashupbubble="false" addmarkerlist="Explorers Rd, Lapstone NSW 2773{}4-default.png{}Lapstone Public School Grounds" bubbleautopan="true" showbike="false" showtraffic="false" showpanoramio="false"]

 [/himage]
```

This is the code for the Plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Akismet
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Akismet
Plugin URI: http://akismet.com/?return=true
Description: Used by millions, Akismet is quite possibly the best way in the world to <strong>protect your blog from comment and trackback spam</strong>. It keeps your site protected from spam even while you sleep. To get started: 1) Click the "Activate" link to the left of this description, 2) <a href="http://akismet.com/get/?return=true">Sign up for an Akismet API key</a>, and 3) Go to your <a href="admin.php?page=akismet-key-config">Akismet configuration</a> page, and save your API key.
Version: 2.5.6
Author: Automattic
Author URI: http://automattic.com/wordpress-plugins/
License: GPLv2 or later
*/

/*
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, USA.
*/

define('AKISMET_VERSION', '2.5.6');
define('AKISMET_PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ));

/** If you hardcode a WP.com API key here, all key config screens will be hidden */
if ( defined('WPCOM_API_KEY') )
    $wpcom_api_key = constant('WPCOM_API_KEY');
else
    $wpcom_api_key = '';

// Make sure we don't expose any info if called directly
if ( !function_exists( 'add_action' ) ) {
    echo "Hi there!  I'm just a plugin, not much I can do when called directly.";
    exit;
}

if ( isset($wp_db_version) && $wp_db_version <= 9872 )
    include_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/legacy.php';

include_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/widget.php';

if ( is_admin() )
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/admin.php';

function akismet_init() {
    global $wpcom_api_key, $akismet_api_host, $akismet_api_port;

    if ( $wpcom_api_key )
        $akismet_api_host = $wpcom_api_key . '.rest.akismet.com';
    else
        $akismet_api_host = get_option('wordpress_api_key') . '.rest.akismet.com';

    $akismet_api_port = 80;
}
add_action('init', 'akismet_init');

function akismet_get_key() {
    global $wpcom_api_key;
    if ( !empty($wpcom_api_key) )
        return $wpcom_api_key;
    return get_option('wordpress_api_key');
}

function akismet_check_key_status( $key, $ip = null ) {
    global $akismet_api_host, $akismet_api_port, $wpcom_api_key;
    $blog = urlencode( get_option('home') );
    if ( $wpcom_api_key )
        $key = $wpcom_api_key;
    $response = akismet_http_post("key=$key&blog=$blog", 'rest.akismet.com', '/1.1/verify-key', $akismet_api_port, $ip);
    return $response;
}

// given a response from an API call like akismet_check_key_status(), update the alert code options if an alert is present.
function akismet_update_alert( $response ) {
    $code = $msg = null;
    if ( isset($response[0]['x-akismet-alert-code']) ) {
        $code = $response[0]['x-akismet-alert-code'];
        $msg = $response[0]['x-akismet-alert-msg'];
    }

    // only call update_option() if the value has changed
    if ( $code != get_option( 'akismet_alert_code' ) ) {
        update_option( 'akismet_alert_code', $code );
        update_option( 'akismet_alert_msg', $msg );
    }
}

function akismet_verify_key( $key, $ip = null ) {
    $response = akismet_check_key_status( $key, $ip );
    akismet_update_alert( $response );
    if ( !is_array($response) || !isset($response[1]) || $response[1] != 'valid' && $response[1] != 'invalid' )
        return 'failed';
    return $response[1];
}

// if we're in debug or test modes, use a reduced service level so as not to polute training or stats data
function akismet_test_mode() {
    if ( defined('AKISMET_TEST_MODE') && AKISMET_TEST_MODE )
        return true;
    return false;
}

// return a comma-separated list of role names for the given user
function akismet_get_user_roles($user_id ) {
    $roles = false;

    if ( !class_exists('WP_User') )
        return false;

    if ( $user_id > 0 ) {
        $comment_user = new WP_User($user_id);
        if ( isset($comment_user->roles) )
            $roles = join(',', $comment_user->roles);
    }

    if ( is_multisite() && is_super_admin( $user_id ) ) {
        if ( empty( $roles ) ) {
            $roles = 'super_admin';
        } else {
            $comment_user->roles[] = 'super_admin';
            $roles = join( ',', $comment_user->roles );
        }
    }

    return $roles;
}

// Returns array with headers in $response[0] and body in $response[1]
function akismet_http_post($request, $host, $path, $port = 80, $ip=null) {
    global $wp_version;

    $akismet_ua = "WordPress/{$wp_version} | ";
    $akismet_ua .= 'Akismet/' . constant( 'AKISMET_VERSION' );

    $akismet_ua = apply_filters( 'akismet_ua', $akismet_ua );

    $content_length = strlen( $request );

    $http_host = $host;
    // use a specific IP if provided
    // needed by akismet_check_server_connectivity()
    if ( $ip && long2ip( ip2long( $ip ) ) ) {
        $http_host = $ip;
    } else {
        $http_host = $host;
    }

    // use the WP HTTP class if it is available
    if ( function_exists( 'wp_remote_post' ) ) {
        $http_args = array(
            'body'          => $request,
            'headers'       => array(
                'Content-Type'  => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; ' .
                                    'charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' ),
                'Host'          => $host,
                'User-Agent'    => $akismet_ua
            ),
            'httpversion'   => '1.0',
            'timeout'       => 15
        );
        $akismet_url = "http://{$http_host}{$path}";
        $response = wp_remote_post( $akismet_url, $http_args );
        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) )
            return '';

        return array( $response['headers'], $response['body'] );
    } else {
        $http_request  = "POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $http_request .= "Host: $host\r\n";
        $http_request .= 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset') . "\r\n";
        $http_request .= "Content-Length: {$content_length}\r\n";
        $http_request .= "User-Agent: {$akismet_ua}\r\n";
        $http_request .= "\r\n";
        $http_request .= $request;

        $response = '';
        if( false != ( $fs = @fsockopen( $http_host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10 ) ) ) {
            fwrite( $fs, $http_request );

            while ( !feof( $fs ) )
                $response .= fgets( $fs, 1160 ); // One TCP-IP packet
            fclose( $fs );
            $response = explode( "\r\n\r\n", $response, 2 );
        }
        return $response;
    }
}

// filter handler used to return a spam result to pre_comment_approved
function akismet_result_spam( $approved ) {
    // bump the counter here instead of when the filter is added to reduce the possibility of overcounting
    if ( $incr = apply_filters('akismet_spam_count_incr', 1) )
        update_option( 'akismet_spam_count', get_option('akismet_spam_count') + $incr );
    // this is a one-shot deal
    remove_filter( 'pre_comment_approved', 'akismet_result_spam' );
    return 'spam';
}

function akismet_result_hold( $approved ) {
    // once only
    remove_filter( 'pre_comment_approved', 'akismet_result_hold' );
    return '0';
}

// how many approved comments does this author have?
function akismet_get_user_comments_approved( $user_id, $comment_author_email, $comment_author, $comment_author_url ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( !empty($user_id) )
        return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE user_id = %d AND comment_approved = 1", $user_id ) );

    if ( !empty($comment_author_email) )
        return $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_author_email = %s AND comment_author = %s AND comment_author_url = %s AND comment_approved = 1", $comment_author_email, $comment_author, $comment_author_url ) );

    return 0;
}

function akismet_microtime() {
    $mtime = explode( ' ', microtime() );
    return $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
}

// log an event for a given comment, storing it in comment_meta
function akismet_update_comment_history( $comment_id, $message, $event=null ) {
    global $current_user;

    // failsafe for old WP versions
    if ( !function_exists('add_comment_meta') )
        return false;

    $user = '';
    if ( is_object($current_user) && isset($current_user->user_login) )
        $user = $current_user->user_login;

    $event = array(
        'time' => akismet_microtime(),
        'message' => $message,
        'event' => $event,
        'user' => $user,
    );

    // $unique = false so as to allow multiple values per comment
    $r = add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'akismet_history', $event, false );
}

// get the full comment history for a given comment, as an array in reverse chronological order
function akismet_get_comment_history( $comment_id ) {

    // failsafe for old WP versions
    if ( !function_exists('add_comment_meta') )
        return false;

    $history = get_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'akismet_history', false );
    usort( $history, 'akismet_cmp_time' );
    return $history;
}

function akismet_cmp_time( $a, $b ) {
    return $a['time'] > $b['time'] ? -1 : 1;
}

// this fires on wp_insert_comment.  we can't update comment_meta when akismet_auto_check_comment() runs
// because we don't know the comment ID at that point.
function akismet_auto_check_update_meta( $id, $comment ) {
    global $akismet_last_comment;

    // failsafe for old WP versions
    if ( !function_exists('add_comment_meta') )
        return false;

    // wp_insert_comment() might be called in other contexts, so make sure this is the same comment
    // as was checked by akismet_auto_check_comment
    if ( is_object($comment) && !empty($akismet_last_comment) && is_array($akismet_last_comment) ) {
        if ( intval($akismet_last_comment['comment_post_ID']) == intval($comment->comment_post_ID)
            && $akismet_last_comment['comment_author'] == $comment->comment_author
            && $akismet_last_comment['comment_author_email'] == $comment->comment_author_email ) {
                // normal result: true or false
                if ( $akismet_last_comment['akismet_result'] == 'true' ) {
                    update_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'akismet_result', 'true' );
                    akismet_update_comment_history( $comment->comment_ID, __('Akismet caught this comment as spam'), 'check-spam' );
                    if ( $comment->comment_approved != 'spam' )
                        akismet_update_comment_history( $comment->comment_ID, sprintf( __('Comment status was changed to %s'), $comment->comment_approved), 'status-changed'.$comment->comment_approved );
                } elseif ( $akismet_last_comment['akismet_result'] == 'false' ) {
                    update_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'akismet_result', 'false' );
                    akismet_update_comment_history( $comment->comment_ID, __('Akismet cleared this comment'), 'check-ham' );
                    if ( $comment->comment_approved == 'spam' ) {
                        if ( wp_blacklist_check($comment->comment_author, $comment->comment_author_email, $comment->comment_author_url, $comment->comment_content, $comment->comment_author_IP, $comment->comment_agent) )
                            akismet_update_comment_history( $comment->comment_ID, __('Comment was caught by wp_blacklist_check'), 'wp-blacklisted' );
                        else
                            akismet_update_comment_history( $comment->comment_ID, sprintf( __('Comment status was changed to %s'), $comment->comment_approved), 'status-changed-'.$comment->comment_approved );
                    }
                // abnormal result: error
                } else {
                    update_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'akismet_error', time() );
                    akismet_update_comment_history( $comment->comment_ID, sprintf( __('Akismet was unable to check this comment (response: %s), will automatically retry again later.'), substr($akismet_last_comment['akismet_result'], 0, 50)), 'check-error' );
                }

                // record the complete original data as submitted for checking
                if ( isset($akismet_last_comment['comment_as_submitted']) )
                    update_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'akismet_as_submitted', $akismet_last_comment['comment_as_submitted'] );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_comment', 'akismet_auto_check_update_meta', 10, 2 );


function akismet_auto_check_comment( $commentdata ) {
    global $akismet_api_host, $akismet_api_port, $akismet_last_comment;

    $comment = $commentdata;
    $comment['user_ip']    = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $comment['user_agent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $comment['referrer']   = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $comment['blog']       = get_option('home');
    $comment['blog_lang']  = get_locale();
    $comment['blog_charset'] = get_option('blog_charset');
    $comment['permalink']  = get_permalink($comment['comment_post_ID']);

    if ( !empty( $comment['user_ID'] ) ) {
        $comment['user_role'] = akismet_get_user_roles($comment['user_ID']);
    }

    $akismet_nonce_option = apply_filters( 'akismet_comment_nonce', get_option( 'akismet_comment_nonce' ) );
    $comment['akismet_comment_nonce'] = 'inactive';
    if ( $akismet_nonce_option == 'true' || $akismet_nonce_option == '' ) {
        $comment['akismet_comment_nonce'] = 'failed';
        if ( isset( $_POST['akismet_comment_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['akismet_comment_nonce'], 'akismet_comment_nonce_' . $comment['comment_post_ID'] ) )
            $comment['akismet_comment_nonce'] = 'passed';

        // comment reply in wp-admin
        if ( isset( $_POST['_ajax_nonce-replyto-comment'] ) && check_ajax_referer( 'replyto-comment', '_ajax_nonce-replyto-comment' ) )
            $comment['akismet_comment_nonce'] = 'passed';

    }

    if ( akismet_test_mode() )
        $comment['is_test'] = 'true';

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( is_string($value) )
            $comment["POST_{$key}"] = $value;
    }

    $ignore = array( 'HTTP_COOKIE', 'HTTP_COOKIE2', 'PHP_AUTH_PW' );

    foreach ( $_SERVER as $key => $value ) {
        if ( !in_array( $key, $ignore ) && is_string($value) )
            $comment["$key"] = $value;
        else
            $comment["$key"] = '';
    }

    $post = get_post( $comment['comment_post_ID'] );
    $comment[ 'comment_post_modified_gmt' ] = $post->post_modified_gmt;

    $query_string = '';
    foreach ( $comment as $key => $data )
        $query_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode( stripslashes($data) ) . '&';

    $commentdata['comment_as_submitted'] = $comment;

    $response = akismet_http_post($query_string, $akismet_api_host, '/1.1/comment-check', $akismet_api_port);
    akismet_update_alert( $response );
    $commentdata['akismet_result'] = $response[1];
    if ( 'true' == $response[1] ) {
        // akismet_spam_count will be incremented later by akismet_result_spam()
        add_filter('pre_comment_approved', 'akismet_result_spam');

        do_action( 'akismet_spam_caught' );

        $last_updated = strtotime( $post->post_modified_gmt );
        $diff = time() - $last_updated;
        $diff = $diff / 86400;

        if ( $post->post_type == 'post' && $diff > 30 && get_option( 'akismet_discard_month' ) == 'true' && empty($comment['user_ID']) ) {
            // akismet_result_spam() won't be called so bump the counter here
            if ( $incr = apply_filters('akismet_spam_count_incr', 1) )
                update_option( 'akismet_spam_count', get_option('akismet_spam_count') + $incr );
            wp_safe_redirect( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
            die();
        }
    }

    // if the response is neither true nor false, hold the comment for moderation and schedule a recheck
    if ( 'true' != $response[1] && 'false' != $response[1] ) {
        if ( !current_user_can('moderate_comments') ) {
            add_filter('pre_comment_approved', 'akismet_result_hold');
        }
        if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'akismet_schedule_cron_recheck' ) ) {
            wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 1200, 'akismet_schedule_cron_recheck' );
        }
    }

    if ( function_exists('wp_next_scheduled') && function_exists('wp_schedule_event') ) {
        // WP 2.1+: delete old comments daily
        if ( !wp_next_scheduled('akismet_scheduled_delete') )
            wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'akismet_scheduled_delete');
    } elseif ( (mt_rand(1, 10) == 3) ) {
        // WP 2.0: run this one time in ten
        akismet_delete_old();
    }
    $akismet_last_comment = $commentdata;

    akismet_fix_scheduled_recheck();
    return $commentdata;
}

add_action('preprocess_comment', 'akismet_auto_check_comment', 1);

function akismet_delete_old() {
    global $wpdb;
    $now_gmt = current_time('mysql', 1);
    $comment_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT comment_id FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE DATE_SUB('$now_gmt', INTERVAL 15 DAY) > comment_date_gmt AND comment_approved = 'spam'");
    if ( empty( $comment_ids ) )
        return;

    $comma_comment_ids = implode( ', ', array_map('intval', $comment_ids) );

    do_action( 'delete_comment', $comment_ids );
    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_id IN ( $comma_comment_ids )");
    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM $wpdb->commentmeta WHERE comment_id IN ( $comma_comment_ids )");
    clean_comment_cache( $comment_ids );
    $n = mt_rand(1, 5000);
    if ( apply_filters('akismet_optimize_table', ($n == 11)) ) // lucky number
        $wpdb->query("OPTIMIZE TABLE $wpdb->comments");

}

function akismet_delete_old_metadata() { 
    global $wpdb; 

    $now_gmt = current_time( 'mysql', 1 ); 
    $interval = apply_filters( 'akismet_delete_commentmeta_interval', 15 );

    # enfore a minimum of 1 day
    $interval = absint( $interval );
    if ( $interval < 1 ) {
        return;
    }

    // akismet_as_submitted meta values are large, so expire them 
    // after $interval days regardless of the comment status 
    while ( TRUE ) {
        $comment_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT $wpdb->comments.comment_id FROM $wpdb->commentmeta INNER JOIN $wpdb->comments USING(comment_id) WHERE meta_key = 'akismet_as_submitted' AND DATE_SUB('$now_gmt', INTERVAL {$interval} DAY) > comment_date_gmt LIMIT 10000" ); 

        if ( empty( $comment_ids ) ) {
            return; 
        }

        foreach ( $comment_ids as $comment_id ) {
            delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'akismet_as_submitted' );
        }
    }

    /*
    $n = mt_rand( 1, 5000 ); 
    if ( apply_filters( 'akismet_optimize_table', ( $n == 11 ), 'commentmeta' ) ) { // lucky number 
        $wpdb->query( "OPTIMIZE TABLE $wpdb->commentmeta" ); 
    }
    */
} 

add_action('akismet_scheduled_delete', 'akismet_delete_old');
add_action('akismet_scheduled_delete', 'akismet_delete_old_metadata'); 

function akismet_check_db_comment( $id, $recheck_reason = 'recheck_queue' ) {
    global $wpdb, $akismet_api_host, $akismet_api_port;

    $id = (int) $id;
    $c = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_ID = '$id'", ARRAY_A );
    if ( !$c )
        return;

    $c['user_ip']    = $c['comment_author_IP'];
    $c['user_agent'] = $c['comment_agent'];
    $c['referrer']   = '';
    $c['blog']       = get_option('home');
    $c['blog_lang']  = get_locale();
    $c['blog_charset'] = get_option('blog_charset');
    $c['permalink']  = get_permalink($c['comment_post_ID']);
    $id = $c['comment_ID'];
    if ( akismet_test_mode() )
        $c['is_test'] = 'true';
    $c['recheck_reason'] = $recheck_reason;

    $query_string = '';
    foreach ( $c as $key => $data )
    $query_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode( stripslashes($data) ) . '&';

    $response = akismet_http_post($query_string, $akismet_api_host, '/1.1/comment-check', $akismet_api_port);
    return $response[1];
}

function akismet_cron_recheck() {
    global $wpdb;

    $status = akismet_verify_key( akismet_get_key() );
    if ( get_option( 'akismet_alert_code' ) || $status == 'invalid' ) {
        // since there is currently a problem with the key, reschedule a check for 6 hours hence
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 21600, 'akismet_schedule_cron_recheck' );
        return false;
    }

    delete_option('akismet_available_servers');

    $comment_errors = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT comment_id
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta
        WHERE meta_key = 'akismet_error'
        LIMIT 100
    " );

    foreach ( (array) $comment_errors as $comment_id ) {
        // if the comment no longer exists, or is too old, remove the meta entry from the queue to avoid getting stuck
        $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
        if ( !$comment || strtotime( $comment->comment_date_gmt ) < strtotime( "-15 days" ) ) {
            delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'akismet_error' );
            continue;
        }

        add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'akismet_rechecking', true );
        $status = akismet_check_db_comment( $comment_id, 'retry' );

        $msg = '';
        if ( $status == 'true' ) {
            $msg = __( 'Akismet caught this comment as spam during an automatic retry.' );
        } elseif ( $status == 'false' ) {
            $msg = __( 'Akismet cleared this comment during an automatic retry.' );
        }

        // If we got back a legit response then update the comment history
        // other wise just bail now and try again later.  No point in
        // re-trying all the comments once we hit one failure.
        if ( !empty( $msg ) ) {
            delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'akismet_error' );
            akismet_update_comment_history( $comment_id, $msg, 'cron-retry' );
            update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'akismet_result', $status );
            // make sure the comment status is still pending.  if it isn't, that means the user has already moved it elsewhere.
            $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
            if ( $comment && 'unapproved' == wp_get_comment_status( $comment_id ) ) {
                if ( $status == 'true' ) {
                    wp_spam_comment( $comment_id );
                } elseif ( $status == 'false' ) {
                    // comment is good, but it's still in the pending queue.  depending on the moderation settings
                    // we may need to change it to approved.
                    if ( check_comment($comment->comment_author, $comment->comment_author_email, $comment->comment_author_url, $comment->comment_content, $comment->comment_author_IP, $comment->comment_agent, $comment->comment_type) )
                        wp_set_comment_status( $comment_id, 1 );
                }
            }
        } else {
            delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'akismet_rechecking' );
            wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 1200, 'akismet_schedule_cron_recheck' );
            return;
        }
        delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'akismet_rechecking' );
    }

    $remaining = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->commentmeta WHERE meta_key = 'akismet_error'" ) );
    if ( $remaining && !wp_next_scheduled('akismet_schedule_cron_recheck') ) {
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 1200, 'akismet_schedule_cron_recheck' );
    }
}
add_action( 'akismet_schedule_cron_recheck', 'akismet_cron_recheck' );

function akismet_add_comment_nonce( $post_id ) {
    echo '<p style="display: none;">';
    wp_nonce_field( 'akismet_comment_nonce_' . $post_id, 'akismet_comment_nonce', FALSE );
    echo '</p>';
}

$akismet_comment_nonce_option = apply_filters( 'akismet_comment_nonce', get_option( 'akismet_comment_nonce' ) );

if ( $akismet_comment_nonce_option == 'true' || $akismet_comment_nonce_option == '' )
    add_action( 'comment_form', 'akismet_add_comment_nonce' );

global $wp_version;
if ( '3.0.5' == $wp_version ) { 
    remove_filter( 'comment_text', 'wp_kses_data' ); 
    if ( is_admin() ) 
        add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wp_kses_post' ); 
}

function akismet_fix_scheduled_recheck() {
    $future_check = wp_next_scheduled( 'akismet_schedule_cron_recheck' );
    if ( !$future_check ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( get_option( 'akismet_alert_code' ) > 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    $check_range = time() + 1200;
    if ( $future_check > $check_range ) {
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'akismet_schedule_cron_recheck' );
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 300, 'akismet_schedule_cron_recheck' );
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the Akismet plugin code, please change it for the right plugin

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some very simple html and css.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="map">
    <div class="map-image">
        <img src="map.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="map-google">
        // code for map goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.map {position:relative;width:400px;height:400px;}

.map-image {position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;z-index:1;}

.map-google {position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;z-index:0;}

.map-image:hover {display:none;}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply but it didn't work. I used the exact code you show and modified it to show the path of the static image and the google map code and I've check for any errors I may have made. It shows the google map below the static image. I'm not sure why. Thank you again!